# how to convert a responseText into a json

Tags: html, ajax, json

I have as a xmlhttp.responseText that:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "45",
               "short_name" : "45",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            }
      ...lines of more json code
      }
...lines of more json code
}
```

**Here is the link with all the lines of the json code**: [json geomaps](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=42.3600077,1.4579696&language=es&sensor=false)

so, how to use that response as a json? like i put it on a variable like that:

```
var json=xmlhttp.responseText
```

And then show the variable json as i want like:

```
json.results.address_components.long_name
```

I thougt it would be easy but I don't know how to resolve that.

What i want to do it's to put the json.results.address_comp... into a value on a form:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Serveis de geocodificació</legend>

    Latitud:<br><input type="text" id="lat" value="42.3600077"/><br>
    Longitud:<br><input type="text" id="lng" value="1.4579696"/><br>

    <input type="button" value="Veure dades" onclick="primerSelect(document.getElementById('lat').value, document.getElementById('lng').value)"/>
    <input type="button" value="Veure coordenades"/><br>

    Carrer:<br><input type="text" id="car"/><br>
    Ciutat:<br><input type="text" id="ciu"/><br>
    Pais:<br><input type="text" id="pai"/><br>
    CP:<br><input type="text" id="cod"/><br>
    <div id="txtHint"></div>
</fieldset>
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

parse the JSON like this

```
var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
var results = json.results;
for (var x in results) {
    var address_components = results[x].address_components;
    for (var i in address_components) {
        console.log(address_components[i].long_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: that's now a json thanks, so, how to get the long_name for example? json.results[0][0].long_name? that's not correct it's wrong...

Comment: @jvillegas is `result` an array of `"address_components"`?

Comment: I thougt that the result is an array with a subarray named address_components

Comment: I put a link with all the json code, maybe it can helps to understand it, thx

Comment: @jvillegas you might need 2 loops because the arrays are nested, maybe some typos but you get the point ;)

Comment: so, @meda, can you answer me with a simple example to explain it better? mhm maybe i need to use a foreach, but that's te first time i work with a json that has generated a lot of code, sometimes i work with simple jsons, and i don't need to loop them, and these jsons have arrays too :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51466/discussion-between-meda-and-jvillegas)

Comment: you are the boss, i depurate it another time and there are simple mistakes I forgiven in my code, thanks really, I can continue developing it and implement it later into the web, have a nice weekend bro!